# Disallow execution in home directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there any way to disallow file execution from home director in Linux? My target is to protect my system from malicious scripts etc. Sure, I can remove execution bit with chmod for `/home/user` and all its subdirectories but it easy could be changed since `user` is owner of `/home/user`. So I think about enabling execution from `bin`, `/usr/bin`, `usr/sbin` only and disallow execution from other directories. My system is Debian 8.

Comment: You would have to do the same to /tmp and /var/tmp at least...

Comment: Oh, and are we talking about a desktop user (as would appear from your description) or a user running a service (which you could restrict far, far more without breaking functionality)?

Comment: While I'm not sure I support the premise of the question, another option may be [SELinux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/How_does_a_process_get_into_a_certain_context#Execute_rights_on_the_file)

Comment: How would this add security? There is always `sh myscript`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. if `/home` is a separate partition, you can mount it with the `noexec` option.
2. By doing this, you are destroying (or attempting to) much of the functionality of a unix system for your users as it disables ALL user-written scripts, not just "malicious" ones.  Writing scripts to get stuff done is a perfectly normal thing for unix users to do.
3. It still doesn't stop them from writing scripts and executing them with `bash myscript.sh` or `perl myscript.pl` etc.
4. If you don't have at least minimal trust in your users, don't give them a shell, or give them a restricted shell such as `/bin/rbash` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: yes, you are right, I've forget about 3. Actually I was talking about my working machine so there isn't other users. All I want to do is protect my system and mostly my home directory from malicious scripts that can get onto a machine via the browser etc.

Comment: Run NoScript and AdBlock Plus in your browser.  Or similar if you're not using firefox/iceweasel.  Only allow web sites that you trust and need and won't work without scripting to run scripts.  e.g. StackExchange is one of the very few sites that I allow to run scripts on my system (and even then well-known advertising and spyware script URLs are still blocked)....but the default is that scripts are disabled until I explicitly enable them for a site.

Comment: You can still use `noexec` even if it is on the same file system: `mount --bind /home /home && mount -o remount,noexec /home`

Comment: @kasperd true.  btw, what does that do to files under /home that were open at the time of the bind mount?

Comment: @cas Anything open at the time of the bind mount will keep using the directory structure hidden by the bind mount. That means users who logged in before the bind mount was performed likely have a current directory hidden by the bind mount. So they would be able to execute files. But changing directory through a full path would leave the hidden directory-hierarchy and instead enter the bind-mounted one without execute permissions. A user logging in after the bind mount would not be able to access the hidden hierarchy and thus cannot execute any executables.

Comment: About #3 even if there was no place that user could put *any* file, executable or not, a script could still be executed by making an interpreter receive it from stdin (eg by downloading it with curl, receiving it with a netcat listener,....)

Comment: If it is a server or otherwise important machine, do not use any Internet browser on it!

Answer (score 3):

A way this could be done is setting up a limited shell for the user - for example using [`lshell`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshell). See also [restricted shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell).

Basically you setup there login shell to be `/usr/bin/lshell` instead of `bash`, then you can configure it via `/etc/lshell.conf` for each user to allow only some stuff to be executed.

However, this may break most programs available to a user without extended configuration - also some programs can be made to execute custom commands which probably could be used to get out of limited shell.

So if you have the correct permissions set on the system (and no `sudo` access, see also what `polkit` allows), they should be able to use the standard login shell without affecting the rest of system.

N.B. another method I know where untrusted users have access to systems is to reimage the entire system every day or so. Not very practical for most cases though.